# how to insert only one column values from one table to another using pl/sql block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

my code is not working  when i run it while inserting values from one table to another table.why this code is not working when insert into statement is right. please refer the table desc is same for both table.

```
    table- desc site_sector 
            ----------- ----- ------------ 
            CIRCLE_NAME       VARCHAR2(50) 
            REF_MONTH         VARCHAR2(50) 
            REF_YEAR          VARCHAR2(50) 
            
            
            
                declare
                type t_list is table of varchar2(50);
                v_array t_list:=t_list();
                begin
                select circle_name bulk collect into v_array from all_sector;
                for i in 1..10 loop
                dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i));
                insert into site_sector(circle_name) values v_array(i);
                end loop;
                end;
        ########################################
        Error report -
        ORA-06550: line 8, column 25:
        PL/SQL: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
        ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
        PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
        06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
        *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilati
    on error.
  
2) This code is also not working
    
    declare
    type t_list is varray(5) of varchar2(50);
    v_array t_list;
    begin
    v_array:=t_list('PB','OR','TN','RJ');
    for i in 1..v_array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i));
    insert into site_sector (circle_name) values v_array(i);
    end loop;
    end;
    
    ############################################################
    Error report -
    ORA-06550: line 8, column 26:
    PL/SQL: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
    ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Comment: hahahha nice one, now you can check error as well. i just want to know , i can insert whole table from one to another using collections but what if i need to insert values only in one column of the table , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper syntax for an [Oracle insert statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423).

```
insert into site_sector (circle_name) values   v_array(i)   ;
```

should be

```
insert into site_sector (circle_name) values ( v_array(i) ) ;
```

You should become familiar with the PL/SQL [FORALL statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB).

Comment: Thanks a lot , i am wonder ,how can i skip that .can